# What is the TECHNICAL Difference between Entity.Contains AND Entity.Attributes.Contains

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

What is the TECHNICAL Difference between  Entity.Contains AND  Entity.Attributes.Contains. I know both of them work, but looking for some technical details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No differences, Entity.Contains is just a shortcut to Entity.Attributes.Contains

Answer (score 1):

No difference as such, Contains internally does 'this.Attributes.Contains(attributeName)' only. Which is similar to Entity.Conatins(attributeName).